Two `FlywayMigrationInitializer`s in one application
The application I am developing makes use of a library which uses Flyway by employing a FlywayMigrationInitializer. My application itself uses Flyway. Therefore after incorporating the library my application has lost the ability to create tables using Flyway. How can I bring back this feature while I still have the tables generated by the imported lib?
